# Is it possible to combine the Jungle variant tile with Cities & Knights?

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

The Jungle Variant involves a jungle hex that produces "Discovery Tokens" which can be used toward purchasing Development Cards.

Obviously, Cities & Knights has no Development Cards to purchase. Is there any sub-variant that allows you to combine the jungle tile with Cities and Knights? Any alternative rules for its use when you play with C&K?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no official ruling on combining the Jungle hex with Cities & Knights, but there are documented suggestions.

[This site](http://www.catanmaps.com/catan-jungle-rules/) has two suggestions:

- Two Discovery Tokens may be traded in for one Resource or Commodity card of your choice.
- Three Discovery Tokens and one Commodity Card may be traded in for one Progress Card of that color.